# .NET Config File: How to check if ConfigSection is present

Tags: c#, .net

Consider:

The line:

`<section name="unity" />`

The block:

```
<unity>
    <typeAliases />
    <containers />
</unity>
```

Say the line is available in the **.config** file while the block is missing.

How to programmatically check if the block exists or not?

**[EDIT]**

For those who geniuses, who were quick to mark the question negative:

I have already tried `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()`

and

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

var section = config.GetSection("unity");

var sInfo = section.SectionInformation;

var isDeclared = sInfo.IsDeclared;
```

Correct me if I'm mistaken, above does *not* return a *null* if the `<configSections>` is defined (even though the actual unity block is missing).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since `ConfigurationSection` inherits from `ConfigurationElement` you can use the `ElementInformation` property to tell if the actual element was found after deserialization.

Use this method to detect whether the `ConfigurationSection` element is missing in the config file:

```
//After Deserialization
if(customSection.ElementInformation.IsPresent == false)
    Console.WriteLine("Section Missing");
```

To determine if a certain element was missing, you can use the property within the section (lets pretend it's called 'propName'), get propName's `ElementInformation` property and check the `IsPresent` flag:

```
if(customSection.propName.ElementInformation.IsPresent == false)
    Console.WriteLine("Configuration Element was not found.");
```

Of course if you want to check if the <configSections> definition is missing, use the following method:

```
CustomSection mySection = 
    config.GetSection("MySection") as CustomSection;

if(mySection is null)
    Console.WriteLine("ConfigSection 'MySection' was not defined.");
```

-Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved this problem.

```
var unitySection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity") as UnityConfigurationSection;
if (unitySection != null && unitySection.Containers.Count != 0)
    container.LoadConfiguration();
```

The first check is for the definition, the second for the block

Answer (score 1):

Use [ConfigurationManager.GetSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection.aspx). This will return `null` if the section does not exist.

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Object
>
> The specified ConfigurationSection object, or null if the section does not exist.

```
if (ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity") == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Section does not exist");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RB, but this does _not_ return a null if the _Line_ is there.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, the point being is that `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()` will not be null if the `<configSections>` is defined (even though the actual unity _block_ is missing).

Comment: Unfortunately this is incorrect answer, when the section is defined but not present it will return default instance (not null) of given configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as this question came up while searching for a solution to the same problem in a `.Net 5` application I'll just leave this here.

In the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#getchildren-and-exists-1) it is stated that

> GetSection never returns null. If a matching section isn't found, an
> empty IConfigurationSection is returned.

To see if the section is empty, use the `Exists` method:

```
var selection = Config.GetSection("section2");
if (!selection.Exists())
{
    throw new System.Exception("section2 does not exist.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to others I think you need to use ConfigurationManager.GetSection(). However, if I read your question correctly are you asking to check if unity exists within a section name="Unity"? If so you will need to do something like:

```
ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity/unity");
```

You can then check against cs if you want or do something similar to what was suggested by RB.

*****EDIT*****

Ok, how about this, it's a bit more long winded but may work:

```
ConfigurationSection section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlData = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xmlData.LoadXml(section);

XmlNode Found = null;

foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in xmlData.ChildNodes)         
{             
    if (node.HasChildNodes) 
    {        
        Found = FindNode(node.ChildNodes, "unity"); 
    }          
}

if(Found == null) //do something
```

Comment: Thanks @sr28, Please correct me if I'm wrong, the point being is that `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()` will not be null if the `<configSections>` is defined (even though the actual unity _block_ is missing).

Comment: @dan - take a look at my edit (not tested). Of course, if 'unity' is the only childnode beneath the section 'unity' you can restructure without the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the configuration file with `xml` reader and navigate to children element named "unity" OR you can implement `IConfigurationSectionHandler` where inside `CreateMethod` you can distinguish the incoming node and  do the checking if it's line or block

```
  public class CustomConfigurationSectionHandler : IConfigurationSectionHandler { 
     public object Create(object parent, 
       object configContext, System.Xml.XmlNode section)
           {
                 //check if section is a line , if yes return null
                 if( section ...)
                 { return null; }
                 //otherwise return whatever result you want :)
                 else {  }
           }
   }
```

the handler needs of course to be registered in the config file so that when you call `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity")` it will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to avoid a XML based solution for this. But seems to be it's the only way to make this happen.

Listing the solution below for the future ref.

[@sr28 and @tchrikch were proposing the same]

```
if (XDocument
  .Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile)
  .XPathSelectElement("/*[local-name() = 'configuration']/*[local-name() = 'unity']") == null)
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use the [ConfigurationManager.GetSection Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection.aspx).

```
if(ConfigurationManager.GetSection(sectionName) == null)
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Liath, but this does _not_ return a null if the _Line_ is present.

Comment: @dan I've reversed it to check for missing rather than not missing

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, the point being is that `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()` will not be null if the `<configSections>` is defined (even though the actual unity _block_ is missing).

Answer (score -1):

You can open your configuration file and try to access the configuration by its name.

```
CustomSection customSection;

            // Get the current configuration file.
            System.Configuration.Configuration config =
                    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
                    ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            // Create the section entry   
            // in the <configSections> and the  
            // related target section in <configuration>. 
            if (config.Sections["CustomSection"] == null)
            {
```

[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.configurationsection.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @elmadj, but this does _not_ return a null if the _Line_ is present.